# Прошу обьяснить принцип работы рекурсии на примере вычисления факториала на JAVA

Tags: java, рекурсия

пример: рекурсивный метод вычисления факториала

```
int fact(int n) {
    if(n==1) return 1;
    return fact(n-1) * n;
}
```

входной параметр число от которого берём факториал
выход значение факториала числа
как присходит вычисление ?

версия 1-
последовательно запускаются методы с уменьшением числа n до 1 затем закрываясь по return последовательно происходит вычисление факториала  по факту выхода из каждого метода
и значение fact в стеке увеличивается по мере закрытия фреймов

версия 2-
при запуске кажного нового метода и создании фреймов в стеке, значение fact в стеке фрейма первого вызова метода увеличивается путём умножения на n при открытии каждого нового (дочернего) фрейма (при вызове следующего метода) и когда доходим до базового в fact уже получен результат

прошу подсказать правильный ответ и где (как) можно видеть значение fact (изменение значения) во время вычисления (погружения в методы)

Comment: Там все очень просто.  Там есть внутренний стек скажем так вложенности задач, когда доходит до return, все задачи начинают подниматься с низу вложенности в верх. Ну как бы всплывают. Объяснение конечно грубое и не  грамотное, так что лучше просто загуглите механизм рекурсии

Comment: это как раз понятно, не понятно как меняется возвращаемое значение метода пошагово и где физически это значение в стеке или в куче

Comment: А вы добавьте вывод в консоль, поиграйтесь, может сами все поймете

Comment: Ну короче если с самого низа то 1, 1×2, 2×3, 6×4,24×5,120×6. 5сли ничего не напутал

Comment: Запятой я отделил вложености

Comment: то есть вариант 1 и значение fact вычисляется в стеке каждого фрейма после закрытия предыдущего или где то в куче тогда значение можно посмотреть, только как?

Comment: не понимаю как вывести на консоль , все что пробую внутри метода запускает метод снова (бесконечно) а снаружи метода всё уже закончилось.

Comment: А что вы пробуете, скиньте код

Comment: Да, первый вариант, главное, чтоб вы понимали, что они запускаются потому что каждый раз внутри доходят до вызова самой себя, пока не дойдут до 1

Comment: System.out.println(this.fact(n)); - бесконечный цикл   System.out.println(this.fact()); ошибка

Comment: В дебагере IJ (значение метода fact пошагово не выводит) ставлю точки остановки пошагово идет вглубь доходит до n=1 затем в раз закрывает все фреймы без пошаговых опреаций выхода если бы вычисления делались в обратном порядке в процессе выхода из методов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уж не знаю кому как, мне обычно помогает рассмотреть все со стороны хардкодного подхода (спасибо VikVik:)), условно вычисление факториала 5 можно реализовать создав 6 методов, образующих последовательную цепочку вызовов, последний из методов - реализация базового случая

```java
public class NumberLogic {

    public static int factZero() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static int factFirst() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static int factSecond() {
        return 2 * factFirst();
    }

    public static int factThird() {
        return 3 * factSecond();
    }

    public static int factFourth() {
        return 4 * factThird();
    }

    public static int factFifth() {
        return 5 * factFourth();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(factFifth());
    }
}
```

Что в принципе и соответствует последовательному рекурсивному вызову

```java
static int factR(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : factR(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Может быть такой подход еще кому-то пригодится

А по поводу памяти: каждый раз когда рекурсивный метод вызывает новый экземпляр самого себя (развертывание стека->), параметры и переменные текущего экземпляра сохраняются в стеке, до того момента пока им не будет снова передано управление(базовый случай->свертывание стека)